# Are there USB to LAN adapter that are compatible with Android 4.0?

Tags: networking

I'm looking for a USB-to-LAN adapter that is compatible with my Chinese Android 4.0 tablet.
I've 2 dongles - [like this](http://www.google.it/imgres?hl=it&biw=1120&bih=595&gbv=2&tbm=isch&tbnid=Gwl-4hB3nzLrrM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.chinatraderonline.com/1/usb-to-lan/&docid=ctpRcT0Fr7CwHM&imgurl=http://www.chinatraderonline.com/Files/USB-Series/USB-Connectors/USB-to-LAN-20160082691.jpg&w=480&h=480&ei=fw6fT86NCoaDOqfYuc4P&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=355&sig=113360772961014795426&page=1&tbnh=123&tbnw=131&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0,i:70&tx=105&ty=41) - but none of them works. 
How can i choose a usb to lan adapter for my Android tablet? 
I've to look at Linux Kernel version to search a suitable adapter?

**Edit**: The model of my tablet is Voyo Q101

Comment: Is there a make or model on your Android Tablet?  Do the directions that come with the tablet promote support for USB devices?  As far as I know, in order for your tablet to support USB devices, it would need USB Host support, and even then, it would need drivers for whatever device you're trying to use.  I've seen people get USB keyboards and mice working, but nothing as complicated as an ethernet controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [XDA-thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1554461) an [Apple USB->Ethernet adapte](http://store.apple.com/us_smb_78313/product/MC704ZM/A)r works on a similar ICS device. So technically it should work. But it in your case it could be hardware limitation, so you should try it out before buying. Just go to an Apple store and ask kindly ;-)